# How to point a domain to a different host and set a GET parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, dns

I have a website on my host and it's connected to a domain, let's say `example.com`. I also have a German version for that site.

The actual site is at:

```
https://example.com/mysite/
```

and when you go to:

```
https://example.com/my-german-site/
```

It redirects to the first link and provides a GET parameter. I use this .htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)lang=de(?:$|&) [NC]
RewriteRule ^my-german-site\/(.*)$ mysite/$1?lang=de [NC,QSA]
```

So visiting:

```
https://example.com/my-german-site/
```

rewrites the URL and it becomes:

```
https://example.com/mysite/?lang=de
```

---

### Question

I bought another domain, `example2.com`. What is the best way to make it serve files from `example.com`? Basically what I want is:

```
https://example2.com/
```

to redirect to:

```
https://example.com/mysite?ex2=true
```

I need this GET parameter because I need to make `example.com` detect when it's been opened from `example2.com` and show the example2 logo.

**What would be the best way to do this?**

Comment: Detect domain name by checking HTTP `Host` header value

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example2.com
RewriteRule . https://example.com/mysite?ex2=true
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=88763f75-0e83-5c57-b005-a190bc8ea1d6